# UISplitViewController EXC_BAD_ACCESS on rotation using ARC

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I am using a `UISplitViewController` on `ARC` but it seems to be crashing after a few rotation events:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x80069f69
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x32461f78 objc_msgSend + 16
1   UIKit                           0x3588b280 -[UISplitViewController _calculateDelegateHiddenMasterOrientations] + 52
2   UIKit                           0x3588cca8 -[UISplitViewController setViewControllers:] + 1344
3   PUC                             0x000d0a42 0x1000 + 850498
4   UIKit                           0x35644ade -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 938
5   UIKit                           0x356be7a4 -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] + 152
```

Also, when I start up the app, I get this error:

```
Splitview controller <PUCSplitViewController: 0x36c290> is expected to have a master view controller before its used!
```

What I have a missed? I set it up very similar to the example project that Apple provided.

Also crashing sometimes when switching the detail view:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // Clicked Asset
    Asset *asset = [items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UIViewController *detailViewController = nil;

    // See what asset we are on
    if ([asset.title isEqualToString:@"News"]) {
        News2 *news = [[News2 alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
        UINavigationController *newsNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:news];
        detailViewController = newsNav;
    } else if ([asset.title isEqualToString:@"Photos"]) {
        PhotosiPad *photos = [[PhotosiPad alloc] init];
        UINavigationController *photosNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:photos];
        detailViewController = photosNav;
    }

    // Update the split view
    [PUCAppDelegate instance].mainSplitViewController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.navigationController, detailViewController, nil];

    // Dismiss the popover if it's present.
    if (popoverController != nil) {
        [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    }

}//end
```

Here is how I create the `UISplitViewController` in `applicationDidFinishLoading`:

```
PUCSplitViewController *splitPUC = [[PUCSplitViewController alloc] init];
self.mainSplitViewController = splitPUC;
[self.window addSubview:self.mainSplitViewController.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Ideas?

Comment: Post your applicationDidFinishLoading code.

Comment: So your splitviewcontroller doesn't have viewcontrollers when the app starts? By the crashlog I bet the uisplitviewcontrolller delegate was released. Please try using zombies.

Comment: Why would it be released? I am using `strong` to keep it around.

Comment: If you get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS it means that you're trying to access a pointer that was already dealloced, if it happens on objc_msgSend then it's probably the object that was supposed to receive the message. And  by reading the rest of the crash log I would bet it's the delegate. Have you tried profiling the app with Instruments?

Answer (score 6):

for the

```
is expected to have a master view controller before its used!
```

error,

you need to set the delegate AFTER you set the view controllers for the splitviewcontroller.

See [Use Your Loaf blog from April 6th, 2012](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2012/04/06/splitview-controller-is-expected-to-have-a-master-view-contr.html)  (No, it is not mine).

Comment: Thank you, I stumbled upon the same problem and the issue was I wasn't setting the delegate to my new detail view controllers. Your answer led the way...